# Color of Scrollbar in a Telerik Radgrid?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

How to change scrollbar color in a Telerik Radgrid?

As its shade appears different in different browsers.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far? ASPX Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the **`Skin`** for **`RadGrad`**. For example:

### ASPX:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="MyScrollbars">
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

### CSS:

```
.RadGrid_MyScrollbars
{
    scrollbar-3dlight-color: #606f94; 
    scrollbar-arrow-color: #4d5874;
    scrollbar-base-color: #f5f5f5; 
    scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #5f6e93; 
    scrollbar-face-color: #d8dfe8;
    scrollbar-highlight-color: #fff; 
    scrollbar-shadow-color: #a3a3a3;
    scrollbar-track-color: #efefef;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a a look here: http://www.telerik.com/support/kb/aspnet-ajax/formdecorator/details/styling-scrollbars.

Also, see if just adding a RadFormDecorator with DecoratedControls=Scrollbars helps.

The issue with scrollbars is that not all browsers will let you style them, because they are not actually part of the page, but a part of the browser UI, like its chrome.